# Cannot figure out why ArrayList.add() isn't working for me

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void findWord(String word) {
  wordsOnBoard = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (dictionary.contains(word)) {
    System.out.println(word);
    wordsOnBoard.add(word); 
  } else {
    System.out.println("None found");
  }
  System.out.println(wordsOnBoard);
}
```

wordsOnBoard is a global ArrayList

When the dictionary.contains(word) it prints out the word and then adds it to wordsOnBoard but then when it leave the if loop the word is no longer in the ArrayList wordsOnBoard.  How would I fix this?

Comment: Which loop? An outer loop? `wordsOnBoard` is a local variable.

Comment: What loop? You haven't written a loop. If you're calling this in a loop, are you expecting the list to be retained between calls? You're using a local variable and creating a new instance each time...

Comment: i ment the if statement.  shouldn't it add each new string passed in into the method into the arraylist?

Comment: @user3044102 In the local `ArrayList` which gets garbage collected when your method returns.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `ArrayList` each time you enter the method.

Then you add something to it (sometimes) and as soon as you leave the method, the object will be eligible for GC.

If you want to keep it around, you should probably put the `ArrayList` into a field of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning your `List`, I suggest you try

```
// pass in your List reference, and then it won't go out of scope.
public void findWord(List<String> wordsOnBoard, String word) {
  if (dictionary.contains(word)) {
    System.out.println(word);
    wordsOnBoard.add(word); 
  } else {
    System.out.println("None found");
  }
  System.out.println(wordsOnBoard);
}
```

Or, you could make `wordsOnBoard` a field in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line: 
  wordsOnBoard = new ArrayList();

from the function and put it where the global variable is actually defined.

When your function comes into scope, this wordsOnBoard will get a local ArrayList with a lifecycle limited to the lifecycle of the function itself. Once the function exits, Garbage Collection will destroy that object.